# How do I change the JSON-LD `@type` from `Article` to `NewsArticle` in WordLift

Tags: wordpress, json-ld, wordlift

I want to change the `@type: Article` exported by the WordLift plugin in JSON-LD to `@type: NewsArticle`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the JSON-LD output before it is sent to the client and change any part of it, e.g. in this specific case:

```
add_filter( 'wl_post_jsonld',  function( $jsonld ) {

  // Bail out if `@type` isn't set or isn't `Article`.
  if ( ! isset( $jsonld['@type'] ) || 'Article' !== $jsonld['@type'] ) {
    return $jsonld;
  }

  $jsonld['@type'] = 'NewsArticle';

  return $jsonld;
} );
```